# jQuery - Ajax - JSON - Simple Contact Form not working

Tags: php, jquery, json, forms

I'm struggling trying to adapt this method of submitting a form. I'm trying to use JSON and understand what is happening here... but I feel like I'm missing something really obvious... I'd really like to get this working. Thank you!

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="span4">
        <div id="formResponse"></div>
        <form id="contactForm" name="contactForm" method="post">
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="span4" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required />
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="span4" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" required />
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <textarea rows="3" class="span4" name="message" id="message"placeholder="Leave your message at the beep..."></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="formSubmit" id="formSubmit" value="Send E-Mail" />
        </form>
        </div>          
        </div>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#contactForm').submit(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/contact.php",
            data: $("#contactForm").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",

                success: function(msg){
                $("#formResponse").removeClass('error');
                $("#formResponse").removeClass('success');
                $("#formResponse").addClass(msg.status);
                $("#formResponse").html(msg.message);

            },
            error: function(){
                $("#formResponse").removeClass('success');
                $("#formResponse").addClass('error');
                $("#formResponse").html("There was an error submitting the form. Please try again.");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Here's the PHP:

```
function checkEmail($email){

if(eregi("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+$]", $email)){
    return FALSE;
}

list($Username, $Domain) = split("@",$email);

if(@getmxrr($Domain, $MXHost)){
    return TRUE;

} else {
    if(@fsockopen($Domain, 25, $errno, $errstr, 30)){
        return TRUE;
    } else {

        return FALSE;
    }
}
}   

$response_array = array();

if(empty($_POST['name'])){

//set the response
$response_array['status'] = 'error';
$response_array['message'] = 'Name is blank';

} elseif(!checkEmail($_POST['email'])) {

//set the response
$response_array['status'] = 'error';
$response_array['message'] = 'Email is blank or invalid';

} elseif(empty($_POST['message'])) {

$response_array['status'] = 'error';
$response_array['message'] = 'Message is blank';

} else {

//send the email
$body = $_POST['name'] . " sent you a message\n";
$body .= "Details:\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
mail($_POST['email'], "SUBJECT LINE", $body);

//set the response
$response_array['status'] = 'success';
$response_array['message'] = 'Email sent!';

}

echo json_encode($response_array);
```

Comment: what's not working ? `console.log(msg)` in success, narrow down

Comment: You need to post someoutput here. Try using the net tab in firefox+firebug. You will be able to see any error returned by the PHP response.

Comment: This issue was that it wasn't posting correctly and the answers below nailed the issue. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what's not working, but I can immediately see that you're not preventing default form submission behavior, and that is a problem:

```
$('#contactForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

That prevents the form from submitting normally so that your ajax will be used instead.  I don't see anything else untoward.

Answer (score 1):

You can also remove the
`<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="formSubmit" id="formSubmit" value="Send E-Mail" />`

and replace it with 
`<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="formSubmit" id="formSubmit" value="Send E-Mail" />`

Use this in your jquery:-

> $('#formSubmit').click(function(){});

instead of:-

> $('#contactForm').submit(function(){});

That would prevent the form's default post behaviour.
Secondly, if you're running your code on localhost, ensure that you have mail server installed, for using php mail() function.

Comment: Thank you, this worked as well... I actually used your solution first but I am giving the right answer to Explosion Pills since it went in first and also worked. Honestly, they're both good solutions.

Comment: Glad to be of some help.. :)